# How to indent selection in TextMate?

Tags: text-editor, textmate

Situation

[image]

I would like to indent the selection and move it to right in TextMate.

How can you indent this kind of selection?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? [4.6.1 Increase/Decrease Indent Level](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text#increase_decrease_indent_level) under [4.6 Moving Text](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text#moving_text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Command+]
```

This works for me.

Comment: what a nasty little shortcut...

Comment: @PatrickT it seems to be a semi-common shortcut. BBEdit, Sublime text, Brackets, Coda, Xcode, and VSCode use it, Intellij does not.

Comment: I see! I don't remember using it, but that's probably because I had remapped it. :-)

Comment: It's not possible to remap keys int textmate :(